# What runtime dependencies does TLBIMP have?

Tags: visual-studio, com, visual-studio-2019, idl

Setting up a clean build machine I have only installed VS2019 so far, including Windows 10 SDK, as far as 3rd-party software is concerned.

An ODL file has custom compile step:

```
midl /out ..\dll %(FullPath)
TLBIMP ../dll/%(Filename).tlb /namespace:MyOrg.COM /keyfile:../include/MyOrg.snk /out:../dll/%(Filename).dll
```

This gives the build error:

> 1>'TLBIMP' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> 1>operable program or batch file. 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(231,5):
> error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 9009.

Clearly MIDL is working, what additional Visual Studio/Windows components do I need to install for TMPLIB?

Comment: TLBIMP https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer "This tool is automatically installed with Visual Studio. To run the tool, use Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt or Visual Studio Developer PowerShell."

Comment: I wonder what's gone wrong then @SimonMourier - on my dev box I can build the parent project/solution just fine. Although I note it's a *.Net Framework Tool* possibly we need a specific version installed. THere's where I'll look next

Comment: TLBIMP is there from .NET day one (or two). `where tlbimp.exe` in dev prompt => `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\TlbImp.exe`

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier you are quite right. Turns out Azure Devops will automatically find the path to msbuild.exe, but it doesn't automatically add the tools to the path based on the chosen SDK. So I was looking on the wrong path, thanks again - I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Simon points out in comments, TLMIMP.exe is a standard VS tool. Depending which Windows SDK is being used it should be found in:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\TlbImp.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools

You might have multiple versions installed, which is used during a build will depend on your `%PATH` variable. This would normally be set whenever you run Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt (I assume if you build within the IDE it's done automatically).

My issue was actually that I'm building with Azure Devops and it doesn't automatically add this folder to the build path.